# about keith wood countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used a plugin on my site which is working well but how do I make it when the countdown ends to call out a div? I am still new to using the plugins.

I was using this code on my JS

```
$(function() {
$('#countdown').countdown({
    date: "June 2, 2016 20:34:26"
});
});
```

This my HTML

```
<div id="countdown">would be display here</div>
```

I want when the countdown end call this div

```
<div id="testing">test</div>
```

My other question is how do I use the keith-wood countdown plugin for counting down again. For example, when the count down ends, auto + 1 day to continue this process? I want `<div id="testing">test</div>` to remain.

This is the [keith-wood countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

Comment: Can you provide the link to the plugin??

Comment: i have updated with the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onExpiry` callback provided by the `plugin`

```
$('#countdown').countdown({
    until: "June 2, 2016 20:34:26",
    onExpiry: liftOff, //call this function and show the div
    onTick: watchCountdown
});

function liftOff(){
    $("#testing").show();
}
```

## [`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/r3w8ych7/1/)

 for your both the questions. I guess you need to use `until` option instead of `date`.

Comment: It works!! thx! but i still have 1 more question which is how do i make the timer wont restart when refresh browser ? i want every user have the same countdown time

Comment: Make use of `localStorage`.. Store the time on every tick in `localStorage` and fetch it on `document.ready` and assign it to the `until` option.